# Payload of captured USB packets is always all-zero in Big Sur M1

Tags: usb, macos-big-sur

I am monitoring USB traffic with Wireshark in the interface XHC2. However, the payload of all USB packets is all-zero. The packet's length is correct, but the packet's payload is all zero. It does not matter which device, which packet or whichever. It is always zero. Obviously, this is not the reality, since the devices work properly and lot of information is displayed via `lsusb`.

My guess is that the XHC interface is setting the payload to 0 before delivering to upper layers, but I do not know if it is intentionally, a bug, kernel issue, my fault or something related with Wireshark.

I also tried `tcpdump -i XHC2` and the saved `pcap` file is the same.

Additional info:

- Mac Mini M1 with Big Sur
- Wireshark ARM 3.6
- SIP disabled

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be related to Wireshark, given that it happened when you captured with tcpdump as well.

You should file an issue on [Apple's Feedback Assistant](http://feedbackassistant.apple.com).